# List web part in modern site does not show any list or the document library to add in share point modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, list-webpart

I am trying to display the document library using the List Webpart available inside a modern page. When I added the List webpart, it does not shows any list/library to add.

Kindly help me in achieving this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern pages, there are [document library web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-document-library-web-part-a9dfecc3-2050-4528-9f00-2c5afc5731b0) for you to display the contents in a document library. Have your tried that?

Comment: Thanks ! there is the web part. I have to display the document library of the root site collection within the sub site.